# SAS, switch rows and columns, for results

Tags: sas, row, transpose

I would like to reformat my printed results, if there is a way.

What I got after running a proc means is:

```
Yearㅣ  #  ㅣ Variable  ㅣ   N ㅣMean
-------------------------------------
1991ㅣ  x  ㅣ   AAAAA   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1991ㅣ  x  ㅣ   BBBBB   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1991ㅣ  x  ㅣ   CCCCC   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1992ㅣ  x  ㅣ   AAAAA   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1992ㅣ  x  ㅣ   BBBBB   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1992ㅣ  x  ㅣ   CCCCC   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1993ㅣ  x  ㅣ   AAAAA   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1993ㅣ  x  ㅣ   BBBBB   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
1993ㅣ  x  ㅣ   CCCCC   ㅣ   x ㅣ x
```

I would like to change this result table so that 1991 1992 1993 are the columns
and I would like the rows presented as:

```
AAAAA
N
Mean
BBBBB
N
Mean
CCCCC
N
Mean
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid your specification of what you want is not exact. Please elaborate.

Comment: Note that I introduced code blocks into your question, so it becomes more compact and readable.

Comment: There are many things to be 'got'. Show the code of the `Proc MEANS` step that you submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displayed output (versus produced output data sets) you can use `Proc TABULATE` to easily arrange your presentation.

`SASHELP.FISH` is SAS sample data set that is likely the same kind of layout as your data.

Example:

Demonstration wise, in `FISH` the variable `species` would correspond to your `YEAR`

Compare and contrast `MEANS` output with `TABULATE` output.  The numbers are the same but the presentation is different (stats in rows instead of columns).

```
proc means data=sashelp.fish n mean ;
  class species;
  var weight height width;
  where species =: 'P';  * limit for demonstration;
run;


proc tabulate data=sashelp.fish;
  title "Tabulate";  
  title2 font=courier "(weight height width) * (n mean) , species";

  class species;
  var weight height width;

  table (weight height width) * (n mean) , species;

  where species =: 'P';  * limit for demonstration;
run;
```

will produce these two outputs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might not be exactly what you want, but it probably comes close.

```
proc sort data=WHAT_I_HAVE;
by variable year;

proc transpose data=WHAT_I_HAVE out=WHAT_I_NEED;
by variable;
id year
var n mean;
run;
```

*Disclaimer: this is untested code and might need debugging.*